# Cooling a 2,000V laminated steel transformer?

Tags: voltage, transformer, cooling

I have a 2,000V laminated transformer, I use it for high power applications, it gets hot quickly. I was thinking of cooling it with distilled water or mineral oil, but can't think of any decent way to cool the coolant, can someone point me in the right direction.

I guess thanking the community for there answer is something abnormal around here...

Comment: Sounds more like you are using the wrong transformer for the job...

Comment: Car radiator and Fan?

Comment: thats not enough,  it gets very hot very quickly.

Comment: You can submerge it in mineral oil, but this is a different conctruction with other counter measures, like boltzman valve, silcagel filters, regular oil inspection with chromatography. No water is allowed neither nearby, silcagel is used to absorb moisture.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think it's getting so hot. Maybe there's an electrical way to make it run more efficiently?

Comment: X-Ray transformers are often cooled with oil.  This works because they have been designed for the task. They are also most often in intermittent use and the added thermal mass of the oil increases the useable dutycycle of the combination.  The oil also usually provides a certain amount of insulation benefits so except for the mess it is a positive step even if the cooling benefits are limited.

Comment: It is used to power a tesla coil, or sometimes when my solar panel transformer fails, I run it from the 12V Ac I get out of my converter.

Comment: @OzzieSpin oh dear me - is it any surprise it gets hot - how can you tell how much current is being drawn thru the coils when supplying a tesla coil.... then, you use it in a totally different way powered by 12V ac. The operating frequencies are several decades apart - you should be pleased it's still working.

Comment: it was built for high and low power applications, exactly what i am using it for.

Answer (score 1):

Not distilled water. You may have heard that Sandia insulate transmission lines with the stuff, but that's for less than 1 second, with ultra-pure, cooled water, so forget it.

Oil, that's mineral or vegatable, will cool the transformer and increase its thermal mass to some extent. Whether it will make enough of a difference to be worth the mess and bother is another matter.

The problem with trying to liquid cool a transformer is that if it has not been built for that, it will not have gaps between the windings so you can get the oil into direct contact with what's getting hot. Indeed, in a transformer built for conduction cooling, there will not only be no channels to get fluid through, but no voids between layers.

An air-blast may be almost as effective, and a lot less messy, than oil.

Comment: Thank you! very helpful answer, I was thinking of using one of those snail turbo like fans out of a server, and blast air over the primary, how hot can it get before it is damaged (generically)

Comment: What about cooling the core? that gets hot way before the windings are even slightly warm.

Comment: Indeed, what about cooling the core? It's conduction cooled to its free surfaces, so immersion in oil, or fast moving air, will improve things. You could bolt it to a heatsink, what thermal contact could you achieve, with or without machining surfaces? If the core gets hot well before the windings, you may want to decrease the volts per turn, that the flux swing the core operates over, to reduce its dissipation. Throw on a few more primary turns if you have space, run it from a small step-down auto transformer if not.

Comment: I will try that, thinking of submerging it in a non conducting liquid cooled by a radiator, there is about half a inch between the secondary windings and the core.

Comment: Is this '2000V transformer' from a microwave oven? If so, they are horribly over-fluxed, to keep the material cost down, as they know it will operate with a screaming fan, while the end-user pays for the extra power consumption

Comment: it is yes from a microwave oven

Comment: In that case, the standard solution is to remove the shunts, and wind a few more primary turns in the space freed up. Make sure you connect them in phase, rather than in anti-phase, which will make things worse. Make sure you maintain adequate insulation between your extra turns and the secondary. BTW, MOTs are vicious beasts, they are not current limited, and the voltage is high enough that it can jump through dry clothing, and pinholes in insulation. If you get careless and get bit, you will probably stay bit!

Comment: Yes, they are really powerful, but they heat up so quickly.